# Django authenticate method returns None

Tags: django, authentication

I am trying to create a user login. I am registering the user through django's admin page. Username and passwords are entered correctly. 
Also I have tried adding authentication backends to settings.py
I have tried multiple ways but couldn't get it to work.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )
```

My code looks like below :
models.py :

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('user')
        password = request.POST.get('pass')

        user = authenticate(username=username,
                            password=password) ----------> None
        if user:
            if user.is_active():
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Account not active')

        else:
            print('Someone tried to login and failed ')
            print('Username {} and passowrd {}'.format(username, password))
            return HttpResponse('Invalid login details supplied!!')

    else:
        return render(request,'account/login.html', {})
```

Comment: Add `print(request.POST)` to the view to check that the correct data is being submitted. Note that [Django comes with authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) so all you have to do is provide a template, you don't have to write your own login view.

Comment: What does that Account model have to do with anything? What is the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting?

Answer (score 0):

The username and password from the below ones are coming as empty so it is giving none 
username = request.POST.get('user')
password = request.POST.get('pass')

Try to inspect the element from HTML to find the name of the fields from which the data is coming from the template or print the values of username and password variables to cross verify.
use request.POST.get('username'), request.POST.get('password1') but as told it totally depends on the html template. It is safer to clean the data and then go for authentication.

Django has inbuilt Class Based Views for the same purpose. Give them a try